# Get enclosing module in Scala 3 macros

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

How do I get the enclosing module of a macro call.

```scala
package foo.bar
class MyClass:
  val macroReturnValue = SomeMacro.macroCall("someExpression")
end MyClass
```

`macroReturnValue` should contain e.g. `"foo.bar.MyClass"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import scala.quoted.*

object SomeMacro:
  inline def macroCall(s: String): String = ${macroCallImpl('s)}

  def macroCallImpl(s: Expr[String])(using Quotes): Expr[String] =
    import quotes.reflect.*
    def enclosingClass(symb: Symbol): Symbol = 
      if symb.isClassDef then symb else enclosingClass(symb.owner)
    val name = enclosingClass(Symbol.spliceOwner).fullName
    Literal(StringConstant(name)).asExprOf[String]
```

Comment: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/basic-macro-for-line-number/7833

Comment: `Symbol.spliceOwner` was the trick I was missing. It's very painful to navigate the API right now. Metals doesn't show the methods for some reason, and the docs have so much indirection :(